# I need to turn on " SMB 1.0/CIFS Client " in Turn Windows features on or off

Tags: windows, smb

When I click on Turn Windows features on or off rather than default window it opens Server Manager and its add role wizard

Any ideas?

Comment: Idea : You're running Windows Server.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows servers (since 2012), the installation of windows components is handled by the [Server Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/server-manager), which can allow you to manage remote servers as well (not just the local system), or multiple servers at once. This replaces the Windows Desktop "Add/Remove Windows Features" functions of appwiz.cpl, and is the provided gui for managing installed components and features. You will have to use it (or command line), in order to install SMB 1.0.

Roles are about what the server is intended to do, and are general groupings of components that are commonly used together, like for instance the "IIS" Role for a webserver or the "File and Storage Services" role for file/storage servers. This makes it easy to group and categorize your servers, and to maintain a consistent configuration amongst related groups.

See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/server-manager#tasks-that-you-can-perform-in-server-manager) for a list of features that Server Manager supports.

If you want to give Powershell a try, [this command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3#powershell-methods) should enable SMBv1:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol`

Comment: The answer doesn't actually specifically mention this, but in case you did not understand, yes, you need to use Server Manager, Add Roles or Features to enable/disable this.

Comment: @LPChip, touched up per your feedback.

Comment: +1 :) ..........